# Is there a compressed memory available for 12.04? (Not compressed swap)

Tags: 12.04, ram

I have an old machine (Pentium 4, heh) computer, with 1GB of memory.
Memory is the current bottleneck (especially with Unity.)

**System:** 12.04.2 (with legacy X stack.)
Sidenote: Will add a GPU as well, but that only helps Unity, not Firefox for example.

I mean Compressed Memory as in OS X - Mavericks way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading some article and found that Ubuntu already have compressed ram algorithm built in on the kernel. This called zram. This feature just doesn't automatically activated.

Based on this site : http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html
Activate it by installing the config

> sudo apt-get install zram-config

Just try it.

Comment: Yeah, zram is what I was looking for. (Too bad it's not "smarter", but I hope they will improve it over time.)